# railstutorial.org guide - Name Error in "has_many through" Model; Uninitialized Constant User::Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working through Michael Hartl's [Rails 4.0 version](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=4.0#table-following_routes) of creating a Twitter-like app with Users who can has_many Followers through: Relationships, but the wrong constant is being initialized when I try to load a page that invokes any kind of "follow" method.

This is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tweets
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
```

And this is my Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
validates :follower_id, presence: true
validates :followed_id, presence: true

params.require(:followed_id)
end
```

Here is the method that is the root of the error:

```
    <% unless current_user == @user %>
      <div id="follow_form">
    <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
      <%= render 'unfollow' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'follow' %>
    <% end %>
```

Feeds into:

```
def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)
end
```

And the error I receive is:

```
NameError in Users#show
uninitialized constant User::Relationship
```

My routes are set up like this:

```
Project1::Application.routes.draw do
 root to: 'users#index'

 get '/log_in' => 'sessions#log_in', as: :log_in
 get '/log_out' => 'sessions#log_out', as: :log_out

 resources :tweets
 resources :relationships
 resources :users do
 member do
   get :following, :followers
 end 
end
```

[Matthew Berman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259507/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-for-has-many-through-relationship) had a very similar problem, but didn't seem to find a fix. All my pluralization seems to be right, based on Hartl's guide and what I've read elsewhere.

Does anyone have any idea why the Name Error is appearing? Why does it want to initialize User::Relationship when it knows that plain Relationships belong to a user anyway, and the two are in separate models?

Thanks for any help you can provide! This has been driving me nuts.

Comment: Out of interest do you have a `relationship_controller`?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the problem is with your relationship.rb file. Check the name of the file and place : app/models/relationship.rb.

Error indicates that your user.rb class doesn't see relationship.rb

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Turns out I just needed to get rid of "params: require" in the relationship model and change the "relationships.find_by" to "Relationship.find_by" so the right stuff would be initialized.